# Python - файл не найден

Tags: python, файлы, type-error

При исполнении команды

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\Никита.Andrey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\TPWA\\win_a.cmd", "wb")
```

python выдает такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Python\Project\YandexLuceum\windows_activate.py", line 24, in <module>
file = open("C:\\Users\\Никита.Andrey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\TPWA\\win_a.cmd", "wb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\Никита.Andrey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\TPWA\\win_a.cmd'
```

Хотя "wb" должен сначала создать файл а потом уже его открывать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Хотя "wb" должен сначала создать файл а потом уже его открывать

Должен создавать файл но не директорию.

```
>>> open('adsfa','wb')
<_io.BufferedWriter name='adsfa'>
>>> open('folder/adsfa','wb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'folder/adsfa'
```

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Вместо двух бэкслешов (//) попробуйте использовать один слеш (/):

```
file = open("C:/Users/Никита.Andrey/AppData/Local/Temp/TPWA/win_a.cmd","wb")
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).